# Setting two absolutely positioned DIV elements side by side

Tags: css

Here is my HTML

```
 <div id="menuCont">
   <div id="SubMenu">
       <input type="button" value="button1"/>
       <input type="button" value="button1"/>
       <input type="button" value="button1"/>   
   </div>
   <div id="Menu">
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
 #Menu{
    height: 550px;
    width: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    background-color: gray
 }
 #menuCont{
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute
 }
```

I am trying to align elements in a way that.. Menu div should come at the top right position.  Please help me on this.But now it is not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change position on your #Menu.

```
#menuCont {
 position:relative;
}
```

then

```
#Menu { 
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: This is not aligning the second DIV to top right position and it is taking new line with left aligned

Comment: Whoops, had the id's backwards, try now!